# How to translate bank address details in Italian?

Tags: word-choice, english-comparison, vocabulary

I'm trying to translate some text from English to Italian for a formal document. A friend of mine living in Italy (Rome) sent me this translation but I feel is not right.

```
Bank Name:         Banca           
IBAN:              IBAN              
Swift Code:        Codice Swift/BIC        
Bank Address:      Indirizzo Agenzia      
Account Name:      Intestatario c/c           
Account Address:   Indirizzo                      
Reference:         Rif/Causale
```

I feel is a bit wrong. Googling `Agenzia` it seems to mean agency and I'm wondering why `Account Address` is translated simply as `Indirizzo` but Bank address `Indirizzo Agenzia`. Can someone who lives in Italy and knows this stuff help me with this?

Comment: As Dispaccio says, "Indirizzo Filiale" is the correct translation for Bank Address. The rest is ok.

Comment: What does c/c stands for?
Can anyone please explain?

Comment: @StupidAmigo: Welcome to Italian.SE! Please use "Your Answer" box to write a real answer to the OP question. If you want to ask something, use "Ask Question".

Comment: @StupidAmigo in this contest c/c stands for "conto corrente" (see Josh61's answer)

Answer (score 6):

I'd translate as follows:

- Nome della Banca
- IBAN (codice identificativo della banca e del cliente)
- Codice SWIFT
- Indirizzo della Banca (Sede, Filiale o Agenzia di pertinenza)
- Intestazione del conto corrente
- Indirizzo dell'intestatario del conto corrente
- Riferimento/Causale.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Italian banks often use "Codice BIC/SWIFT" because both acronyms represent the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You could translate "Bank Address" in a more pertinent "Indirizzo Filiale" but they are basically the same.

I agree with you regard "Account Address". I would translated it more as "Indirizzo Intestatario"